# For loop for reading strings from a file into a 3D array

Tags: c++, vector, 3d, for-loop, sdl

I'm having a problem with one of my functions, I'm working on a simple tile map editor, and I'm trying to implement a 3D array to keep track of tiles (x,y, layer). Before this I had a 1D array where all the tiles were just listed sequencially:

```
bool Map::OnLoad(char* File) {
    TileList.clear();
    FILE* FileHandle = fopen(File, "r");
    if(FileHandle == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    for(int Y = 0;Y < MAP_HEIGHT;Y++) {
        for(int X = 0;X < MAP_WIDTH;X++) {
            Tile tempTile;

            fscanf(FileHandle, "%d:%d ", &tempTile.TileID, &tempTile.TilePassage);

            TileList.push_back(tempTile);
        }
        fscanf(FileHandle, "\n");
    }
    fclose(FileHandle);
    return true;
}
```

This basically read strings from the file which looked like:

```
2:1 1:0 3:2...
```

Where the first number states the tileID and the second one states the Tile passability. **The above function works**. My 3D arrays are also correctly constructed, I tested them with simple assignments and calling values out of it. **The function that gives me problems is the following** (please note that the number 2 i.e. OnLoad2() was added so I can keep the old variables and the function untouched until the prototype is working):

```
bool Map::OnLoad2(char* File) {
    TileList2.clear();
    FILE* FileHandle2 = fopen(File, "r");
    if(FileHandle2 == NULL) {
        return false;
    }

    for(int Y = 0;Y < MAP_HEIGHT;Y++) {

        for(int X = 0;X < MAP_WIDTH;X++) {
            Tile tempTile;
            fscanf(FileHandle2, "%d:%d ", &tempTile.TileID, &tempTile.TilePassage);

            TileList2[X][Y][0] = tempTile;
        }
        fscanf(FileHandle2, "\n");
    }
    fclose(FileHandle2);
    return true;
}
```

While this function doesn't trigger the compiler to report any errors, as soon as the application starts, it freezes up and crashes. For additional information **MAP_WIDTH and MAP_HEIGHT are set to 40 each** and the 3D array was constructed like this:

```
TileList2.resize(MAP_HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < MAP_HEIGHT; ++i) {
    TileList2[i].resize(MAP_WIDTH);
    for (int j = 0; j < MAP_WIDTH; ++j)
        TileList2[i][j].resize(3);
}
```

I would appreciate it if you could point me out what do I need to fix, as far as I know I must have messed up the for loop structure, as the 3D array initializes and works properly. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The same way as TileList was, except for 3D: std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<Tile> > > TileList2;

Comment: A class. The problem was not there, as Rob figured it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
TileList2.clear();
```

This line reinitializes TileList2, so it is back to a zero-length vector. Delete that line, and you will probably be okay.

Comment: That worked? I thought indexing vectors like that automatically resized...Been a long time since I worked with STL though

Comment: Looks like it doesn't, as removing that lime makes it work properly. I'll accept your answer as soon as the tile limit gets over.

Comment: @Dan, Nope, `std::vector` does not automatically resize in either `std::vector::operator[]` nor `std::vector::at`. If you want to add data to the vector and have it resize, try `std::vector::push_back`.

Comment: Now that I can vote, +1 for making me feel like an idiot :D It was just an old habit from other programming languages that the array should hold it's shape on clear.